# search through xpath only within current scrapy Selector

Tags: css, xpath, scrapy

Using Scrapy, I have extracted a selector like below (I have omitted other tags here for readability)

```
>>> row.get()
'<tr>\n   <td>\n   <span class="severity-list__item-text">H</span>\n   </li>\n              </ul>\n     </tr>'
```

The selector here only contains one instance of span tag with class value "severity-list__item-text". However, the whole page contains 30 like this.

When I write this:

```
>>> l = row.xpath('//span[@class="severity-list__item-text"]')
>>> len(l)
30
```

Here, I was expecting to get only the one value within the given selector. However, it is returning me all the instances present in the page. What is the issue here? How can I limit my serach only within a given selector?

Comment: Have you tried `getall()`? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Comment: yes. `getall()` also gives the string just within a list, a single item list that is. I was hoping to do any further operations only within this selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was missing a '.' to signal to the parent selector.

```
>>> l = second_row.xpath('.//span[@class="severity-list__item-text"]')
>>> len(l)
1
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been hours dealing with this issue. The dot approach helped me :)